# How can I conceal an electrical box mounted on a wall with an angle passing through it?

Tags: electrical, safety, socket

Moved into a house with a 2 gang socket mounted on an angled bit of wall. It's a galvanized steel back box with holes for mounting that have been left exposed. This is in my child's room and starting to think it's not that safe.

I was thinking a simple fix might be to glue some 6mm wooded strips around the exposed backbox, fill/caulk and paint, then call it a day.

Can anyone see any issues with that solution?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would try **1/4" vinyl board stock and double-sided foam tape**. Create cardboard patterns first, and lap the top piece over the sides for best appearance. Cut slightly oversize to allow room for the tape.

You should be able to fit the sides very well, but a tiny bead of paintable caulk would put some polish on the joints.

Answer (score 1):

My recollection of typical UK installs is that the box in question is expected to be buried in plaster. So I'd do that, either with plasterboard or plaster, to create a bump-out (section of non-angled wall surrounding the box) that covers the box properly and provides full bearing for the socket faceplate. It appears that the socket is sitting at an angle due to the lack of support around the box.